# python regex substitute double quote to single quote in a string

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to search and replace some pattern in my string. These are my possible pattern,

1. In the string provided, after the pattern-A '1.3.6.1.4.1.6536.2.7.0 s ' you can see a string(that can have all possible special characters including multiple DOUBLE QUOTE) with in double quote. The end of the string is mentioned with another double quote before the pattern-B "1.3.6.1.4.1.6536.2.13.0".
2. I want to replace the DOUBLE QUOTE after pattern-A to a SINGLE QUOTE and the DOUBLE QUOTE before pattern-B to another SINGLE QUOTE.
3. Problem is the pattern-B is not constant value or it may be the end of line. But, before the pattern B there will be a DOUBLE QUOTE.
4. Also, I want the rest of the string to be same as it is.

my String:

`10.88.141.220 1.3.6.1.4.1.6536 66.187.220.156 6 1 0 1.3.6.1.4.1.6536.2.6.0 s "CIPS" 1.3.6.1.4.1.6536.2.3.0 s "202.39.169.59" 1.3.6.1.4.1.6536.2.21.0 i 48215 1.3.6.1.4.1.6536.2.7.0 s "eventId=1384760064820340493 vendor=Cisco eventType=evIdsAlert hostId=eips1 appName=sensorApp appInstanceId=14679 tmTime=1396009683700 severity=5 interfaceGroup=vs0 Interface=PortChannel0/0 Protocol=tcp riskRatingValue=85 sigId=5842 version=S269 sigDetails="Solaris Telnet Authentication Bypass" src=134.174.9.66 srcDir=OUT_2019 srcport=48215 dst=202.39.169.59 dstDir=OUT_2019 dstport=23 attackerContext="//4B//4B//4B//4B//sf//ofAFAAGf/w//sY//oYAHZ0MTAw//D/+yf/+icA AFVTRVIBLWZhZG3/8P/7H//6HwBQABn/8P/7GP/6GAB2dDEwMP/w//sn//on AABVU0VSAS1mYWRt//A=" physical="Unknown" idSource="unknown" targetValueRating="medium" cid:threatRatingValue="85" cid:triggerPacket="KJQPjJVyxArLBNAACABFAABWz9JAADoGbXyGrglCyiepO7xX ABcQv8jxU+LBD1AZwhDkIAAA//sf//ofAFAAGf/w//sY//oYAHZ0MTAw//D/ +yf/+icAAFVTRVIBLWZhZG3/8E1rFeUW3O7ORTfY7vCmsOVPZnRS/nAFpJ9V aSE+SOSDiLtNtFly/FARHU1cRFWHjko2ld6T3P1lTF0n9KimbwHpTldifaO+ 3FFeTjaehynxnAH7+Sfz1vX9ENfn" context="single_vf" relevance="unknown" type="unknown" backplane="PortChannel0/0" alertDetails="InterfaceAttributes:  context=single_vf physical=Unknown backplane=PortChannel0/0 ; "" 1.3.6.1.4.1.6536.2.13.0 s "Fri Mar 28 07:28:03 CDT 2014" 1.3.6.1.4.1.6536.2.10.0 s "170015" 1.3.6.1.4.1.6536.2.14.0 i 23 1.3.6.1.4.1.6536.2.9.0 s "CPY000000334577~STE000000021185" 1.3.6.1.4.1.6536.2.2.0 s "134.174.9.66" 1.3.6.1.4.1.6536.2.20.0 s "" 1.3.6.1.4.1.6536.2.18.0 s "" 1.3.6.1.4.1.6536.2.4.0 i 5 1.3.6.1.4.1.6536.2.1.0 s "NFE-p1-10:1389503591806-9627475421" 1.3.6.1.4.1.6536.2.11.0 s "Code Injection" 1.3.6.1.4.1.6536.2.8.0 s "eips1" 1.3.6.1.4.1.6536.2.5.0 i 1 1.3.6.1.4.1.6536.2.12.0 i 60 1.3.6.1.4.1.6536.2.17.0 s "Partners Healthcare" 1.3.6.1.4.1.6536.2.19.0 s "no related events" 1.3.6.1.4.1.6536.2.16.0 s "Solaris Telnet Authentication Bypass" 1.3.6.1.4.1.6536.2.15.0 s "5842"'`

Output needed:

`10.88.141.220 1.3.6.1.4.1.6536 66.187.220.156 6 1 0 1.3.6.1.4.1.6536.2.6.0 s "CIPS" 1.3.6.1.4.1.6536.2.3.0 s "202.39.169.59" 1.3.6.1.4.1.6536.2.21.0 i 48215 1.3.6.1.4.1.6536.2.7.0 s 'eventId=1384760064820340493 vendor=Cisco eventType=evIdsAlert hostId=eips1 appName=sensorApp appInstanceId=14679 tmTime=1396009683700 severity=5 interfaceGroup=vs0 Interface=PortChannel0/0 Protocol=tcp riskRatingValue=85 sigId=5842 version=S269 sigDetails="Solaris Telnet Authentication Bypass" src=134.174.9.66 srcDir=OUT_2019 srcport=48215 dst=202.39.169.59 dstDir=OUT_2019 dstport=23 attackerContext="//4B//4B//4B//4B//sf//ofAFAAGf/w//sY//oYAHZ0MTAw//D/+yf/+icA AFVTRVIBLWZhZG3/8P/7H//6HwBQABn/8P/7GP/6GAB2dDEwMP/w//sn//on AABVU0VSAS1mYWRt//A=" physical="Unknown" idSource="unknown" targetValueRating="medium" cid:threatRatingValue="85" cid:triggerPacket="KJQPjJVyxArLBNAACABFAABWz9JAADoGbXyGrglCyiepO7xX ABcQv8jxU+LBD1AZwhDkIAAA//sf//ofAFAAGf/w//sY//oYAHZ0MTAw//D/ +yf/+icAAFVTRVIBLWZhZG3/8E1rFeUW3O7ORTfY7vCmsOVPZnRS/nAFpJ9V aSE+SOSDiLtNtFly/FARHU1cRFWHjko2ld6T3P1lTF0n9KimbwHpTldifaO+ 3FFeTjaehynxnAH7+Sfz1vX9ENfn" context="single_vf" relevance="unknown" type="unknown" backplane="PortChannel0/0" alertDetails="InterfaceAttributes:  context=single_vf physical=Unknown backplane=PortChannel0/0 ; "' 1.3.6.1.4.1.6536.2.13.0 s "Fri Mar 28 07:28:03 CDT 2014" 1.3.6.1.4.1.6536.2.10.0 s "170015" 1.3.6.1.4.1.6536.2.14.0 i 23 1.3.6.1.4.1.6536.2.9.0 s "CPY000000334577~STE000000021185" 1.3.6.1.4.1.6536.2.2.0 s "134.174.9.66" 1.3.6.1.4.1.6536.2.20.0 s "" 1.3.6.1.4.1.6536.2.18.0 s "" 1.3.6.1.4.1.6536.2.4.0 i 5 1.3.6.1.4.1.6536.2.1.0 s "NFE-p1-10:1389503591806-9627475421" 1.3.6.1.4.1.6536.2.11.0 s "Code Injection" 1.3.6.1.4.1.6536.2.8.0 s "eips1" 1.3.6.1.4.1.6536.2.5.0 i 1 1.3.6.1.4.1.6536.2.12.0 i 60 1.3.6.1.4.1.6536.2.17.0 s "Partners Healthcare" 1.3.6.1.4.1.6536.2.19.0 s "no related events" 1.3.6.1.4.1.6536.2.16.0 s "Solaris Telnet Authentication Bypass" 1.3.6.1.4.1.6536.2.15.0 s "5842"`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest solving this using group references.

```
re.sub(r'patternA"(.*?)"patternB', r"patternA'\1'patternB", myString)
```

In your case:

```
patternA = r'1.3.6.1.4.1.6536.2.7.0 s '
patternA = patternA.replace(".", r"\.") # escaping special character
patternB = r'1.3.6.1.4.1.6536.2.7.0 s '
patternB = patternB.replace(".", r"\.")
```

and substitute them in to the regex